# Pushing an array returns Object object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I Have collecion called "capacitaciones", one of it's attributes is an array called "comentarios" I have a problem when I am pushing it, my code returns [Object object], I want you see my model and then my controller:

**Model**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    title:{
        type:'STRING',
        required:true
    },
    urlmp4:{
        type:'STRING',
        url:true,
        required:true
    },
    urlogv:{
        type:'STRING',
        url:true,
        required:true
    },
    likes:{
        type:'integer'
    },
    unlikes:{
        type:'integer'
    },
    comentarios:{
      type:'array'
    }   
  }
};
```

**Controller**

```
comment: function(req,res,next){
    Capacitaciones.findOne({id: req.param('id')}).exec(function (err,capacitacion){
        if (err) return next(err);
        if(capacitacion){
            capacitacion.comentarios.push({"usuario":req.session.username,"comentario":req.param('comentario')});
            console.log(capacitacion.comentarios);
            capacitacion.save(function (err){
                if (err){

                    return next(err);
                }
                res.view('capacitaciones/show', {capacitaciones: capacitacion});
            });
        }
        else{
            return next();
        }
    });
}
```

As you see i want to push two values "Usuario" and "Comentario", you also see my " connsole.log(capacitacion.comentarios); " it returns the values I am pushing but my view returns [Object object]

**View**

```
<div class="row-fluid text-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <legend class="text-success text-left"><strong>Comentarios</strong></legend>
        <form action="/Capacitaciones/comment/<%= capacitaciones.id %>" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comentario" rows="3" maxlength="200"></textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btn">
                 <strong>Comentar</strong>
            </button>
        </form><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid text-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <br>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">

            <% _.each(capacitaciones.comentarios, function(comentarios){ %>
                <tr class="success">
                    <td><h4 class="text-primary text-left"><strong><%= comentarios.usuario %></strong></h4></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p class="text-left"><%= comentarios.comentario %></p></td>
                </tr>
            <% }) %>

        </table>        
    </div>
</div>
```

I really would appreciate your help, thanks and blesses.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code for your view?

Comment: What version of Sails are you using, and which database adapter?

Comment: I am using 0.9.15 and MongoDb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! my problem was my url rule, i was not sending a correct url. Ty